# Trying to pass a parameter to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC - I just want to pass a parameter to my controller.

`<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Basic", "abc")">Basic</a></li>`

Above is in the cshtml

And here's the code in the controller.

`public ActionResult Index(string id)`

I can see the action getting called but nothing is being passed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass route values in an anonymous object:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Basic", new {id = "abc"})
```

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of Url.Action is an object. Try this:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Basic", new { id = "abc" })">Basic</a></li>
```